# como hago para sacar el máximo común divisor de ambos números?

Tags: python

```
def  mcd(lista, a):
    cont=0
    divisores=[]
    for i in range(1, lista+1):
        if(lista % i == 0) and (a % i ==0):
            divisores.append(i)
            cont=cont+1
    return divisores

lista=12
a= 6
print(mcd(lista, a))
```

Definir una función llamada mcd que tome dos enteros positivos y devuelva el máximo común
divisor.

Comment: Entiendo que debiera ser `divisores[len(divisores)-1]`

Comment: muchas gracias :D

Comment: no, pero gracias quizás me sirva para mas adelante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Calcular el MCD usando el algoritmo de Euclides puedes usar la siguiente función

```
def mcd_euclidiano(a,b):
  if b==0:
    return a
  ap=a% b  
  return mcd_euclidiano(b,ap)
```

La idea básica del método de Euclides es dividir el numero mayor entre el menor hasta que el modulo de dicha división sea cero, en cuyo caso divisor que genera este modulo = 0 es el MCD

Puedes encontrar una explicación y ejemplos del método euclideano en [Método de Euclides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=036pOZO0hV4)